# TexWorks used to output PDF from TeX file result in XeTeX required error

Tags: xetex, pdftex, texworks

I'm new with TeX and Linux, but I want to learn to use it.

I found an open source TeX file from [here](https://github.com/afriggeri/cv) and I want to be able to compile from the `cv.tex` file to `cv.pdf`. After searching around, I found pdfLaTeX seems to be what I was looking for. However, using the command line, it gives me the error of `XeTeX is required to compile this document`. I do have XeTeX and when I try to use XeTeX, it gives me the error of `Undefined control sequence`.

Since I am new to Linux and googling increases my confusion, I decided to use TeXWorks which is an IDE I hope will have all the dependencies to compile the `.tex` file to PDF. Upon launching, I believe the "compiler" was set to pdfLaTeX and I click on the "green play button" and it did create a new window with the right content on it. I was ecstatic. I started modifying the `.tex` file, "save" and hit the "green button" again but this time I get the same errors as when I do it through the command line. I get `XeTeX required` when I use pdfLaTeX and `Undefined control sequence` when I use XeTeX.

Can someone please guide me to the right path?

Additional info: If I close TeXworks and open it again, I can the original output `cv.pdf` on another window however, it does not include my changes to `cv.tex`. I also tried XeLaTeX and it does not compile correctly.

The error I get when use XeLaTeX is:

```
LaTeX error file: unicode-math.sty not found
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. (Also, your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.)

Comment: Set the typesetting engine to »XeLaTeX« in the corresponding pull down menu of TeXworks and it should work. Alternatively add `% !TEX program = xelatex` as very first line to the source code and XeLaTeX will be chosen automatically every time.

Comment: I tried xelatex and it also doesn't work. The error I get is uniccode-math.sty not found. @doncherry I'm new to tex so I can't even get a minimal working example. The link that I link to has the .tex file and the .pdf file which is the output that the creator has included as a sample. I'd like to be able to take that .tex file and create my own pdf file. So far, the only thing I change is just the name and address. Thanks.

Comment: @Yko: Then you have to install the »[unicode-math](http://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math)« package. Package installation is usually done by the package manager of your TeX distribution. If you use a TeX system that is provided by your Linux distribution, take a look at the respective repositories and install the missing LaTeX related packages (probably something like texlive-…).

Answer (score 4):

Set the typesetting engine to »XeLaTeX« in the corresponding pull down menu of TeXworks (see picture). Alternatively you can add `% !TEX program = xelatex` as very first line to the source code and TeXworks will choose XeLaTeX automatically every time.

---

[image]